# Choose implementation at load time

Tags: spring

I use spring 3.2.13.RELEASE.
I have a boolean properties in a properties file to activate a version or another.

And I Have the following bean:

```
   public interface VersionBean{
     void doSomething();
    }

    public class FirstVersionBean implements VersionBean{
    }

    public class SecondVersionBean implements VersionBean{
    }

public class Service{
 private VersionBean versionBean;
}
```

Is it possible to inject the firstVersionBean if my boolean is true and if false use secondVersionBean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR**

You can achieve what you want using **Spel** *ternary operator* to check a props boolean value and inject accordingly *beanA* or *beanB* version (Spring 4 gets this idea a step further introducing **@Conditional**).

either using annotations:

```
@Value("#{${flag} ? beanA : beanB }")
private IntAB b;
```

or in XML config:

```
<bean id="beanC" class="com.dimitrisli.example.BeanC">
    <property name="b" value="#{${flag} ? beanA : beanB }"/>
</bean>
```

---

Here's a fully working example with BeanC demo-ing how to do it using XML-defined bean and BeanD how to do it using annotation-defined bean:

**Common Interface**

```
public interface IntAB {

    public String myBean();
}
```

**BeanA**

```
public class BeanA implements IntAB {

    @Override
    public String myBean() { return "BeanA"; }
}
```

**BeanB**

```
public class BeanB implements IntAB {

    @Override
    public String myBean() { return "BeanB"; }
}
```

**BeanC**

```
public class BeanC {

    private IntAB b;

    public void setB(IntAB b) { this.b = b; }

    public String myBean() { return b.myBean(); }
}
```

**BeanD**

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;


@Component
public class BeanD {

    @Value("#{${flag} ? beanA : beanB }")
    private IntAB b;

    public String myBean() { return b.myBean(); }
}
```

**Application Context**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <context:property-placeholder location="app.properties"/>

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.dimitrisli.example"/>

    <bean id="beanA" class="com.dimitrisli.example.BeanA" />
    <bean id="beanB" class="com.dimitrisli.example.BeanB" />
    <bean id="beanC" class="com.dimitrisli.example.BeanC">

        <property name="b" value="#{${flag} ? beanA : beanB }"/>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

**Main**

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ClassPathXmlApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring/application-context.spring.xml");

        BeanC c = (BeanC) ctx.getBean("beanC");
        BeanD d = (BeanD) ctx.getBean("beanD");

        System.out.println(c.myBean());
        System.out.println(d.myBean());
    }
}
```

**app.properties**

```
flag=false
```

Comment: I don't understand why it would be a bad idea. I use the interface in all other injected places.

Comment: Revised my answer since initially I thought you meant swapping Spring version lib. Hope now it's well understood.

Comment: This is exactly what I want. But for the example your should rename your interface (something like Service, FirstService, SecondService, computeSomeValue) and method cause it's a bit confusing like you did.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than create two bean instances and figure out which implementation to use based on the config property, it's probably easier to simply create a single `VersionBean` in the first place.  For example, something like this:

```
@Configuration
public class YourConfigClass {

    private boolean yourBool;

    @Bean
    public VersionBean versionBean() {
        if (yourbool) 
            return new FirstVersionBean();
        else
            return new SecondVersionBean();
    } 

    @Value("${some.config.property}")
    public void setYourBool(boolean value) {
        this.yourBool = value;
    }
}
```

Then you can autowire `VersionBean` into any of your other components.

Comment: That's it, is it not possible to make it with xml configuration ?